# keep getting air in the fuel line

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, renault, kangoo

I put 17 liters of petrol in my Renault kangaroo it already had 8 liters of diesel in it had it drained by mechanic put 12 liters diesel in it took a while but did start and run well until I got 3 miles away there is a lot of air going through the pipes.renault kangoo

Any advice?

Comment: This is a diesel engined vehicle which accidentally had petrol put in it? Now the petrol has been drained and fresh diesel put in?

Comment: yes and it run well for 3 miles then stoped loads of air in the pipes after the filter

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have the fuel pump properly bled to get the air out - the three miles you got was probably down to fuel already in the pipes. I would have expected the mechanic who drained the tank to have re-bled the system after refilling...

Comment: 3 miles is a long way to go on a fuel lines worth of fuel. Put me down as: doubt.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that, looking at [this](http://www.pistonheads.com/gassing/topic.asp?t=917543) thread, you have a loose coupling in your fuel line somewhere.  This may have been caused by presumably disconnecting and reconnecting the lines when the fuel was drained or it may be that the petrol has eroded a gasket / seal.

I'd suggest following the advice in the penultimate post of the link I've posted, namely...

> isolate flow and return fuel lines from the tank. fit pressure gauge to system and manually pressurize. if system does not holding constant pressure for 10-15mins, carefully work your way along the fuel lines to find culprit and replace. it may be something as simple as a union needing tightening up. pay attention to the injectors and injector rail, and any flexible fuel lines.